# Firebase Cloud Functions: Error: Unexpected error while acquiring application default credentials: read ECONNRESET

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When trying to run my firebase cloud function with http trigger, I kept getting this error but only intermittently:

```
Error: Unexpected error while acquiring application default credentials: read ECONNRESET
```

There are some unrelated ECONNRESET/firebase SO answers that provided no solution:
[Firebase Storage & Cloud Functions - ECONNRESET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43224994/2684661)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem:

To initialize my functions I was using:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');    

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Solution (for me at least):

I had to use my Google service account credentials:

```
var serviceAccount = require("./PATH_TO_YOUR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE_GOES_HERE.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_NAME.firebaseio.com"
});
```

To get the firebase project name check the top left corner of your firebase project console (A) .

To Download the service account JSON file click on the (B) gear icon in the top left of the firebase console then click (C) project settings:

[image]

Then click the service accounts tab:

[image]

Then click the "Generate New Private Key to download the file.

You can then move the JSON file into your project functions folder and import it as shown in the code snippet above.

[image]

Comment: When I do this I get the following error: Cannot find module '/Users/nikhilsridhar/Desktop/test-eed0a-firebase-adminsdk-c4tmt-5d905a082b.json'

Comment: Does the key have to be in the functions folder? What am I doing wrong if the is how I define it var serviceAccount = require('/Users/nikhilsridhar/Desktop/test-eed0a-firebase-adminsdk-c4tmt-5d905a082b.json');

Comment: I include the JSON key file in the functions folder and the require goes in the index.js like so: const serviceAccount = require(`./${firebaseProjectName}-firebase-adminsdk.json`); I just modified the filename so that I can dynamically switch between dev/test and production firebase projects. Hope that helps.

Comment: You can git ignore the file so it wont be included in the repo.