# Firebase Admin With Credential

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, credentials, firebase-admin

After coding some of my firebase functions, I deployed and got the following error:

> Unexpected error while acquiring application default credentials: Could not load the default credentials.

I researched this error and came to the conclusion that this post would solve my issue: [Firebase Cloud Functions: Error: Unexpected error while acquiring application default credentials: read ECONNRESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233474/firebase-cloud-functions-error-unexpected-error-while-acquiring-application-de?rq=1)

I tried this solution. I downloaded a new private key to my desktop and then inserted the following code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require('/Users/nikhilsridhar/Desktop/test-eed0a-firebase-adminsdk-c4tmt-5d905a082b.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://test-eed0a.firebaseio.com"
});
```

However this does not solve my problem, but rather gives me a new error:

> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/nikhilsridhar/Desktop/test-eed0a-firebase-adminsdk-c4tmt-5d905a082b.json'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried making it a relative path? so `./test-eed0a-firebase-adminsdk-c4tmt-5d905a082b.json`?

Answer (score 1):

The function admin.credential.cert() receives a string parameter with the path of the firebase json key, this code works well for me with the auth method, you should add databaseURL and call .firestore() instead of auth():

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin'

export default admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert('../../firebase-key.json')
}).auth()
```

---

Watch what TypeScript says about that method:

cert(**serviceAccountPathOrObject: string** | admin.ServiceAccount, httpAgent?: Agent | undefined): Credential
Optional | HTTP Agentto be used when retrieving access tokens from Google token servers.

- The path to a service account key JSON file or an object representing a service account key.

See | Initialize the SDK for more details.

@example

```
// Providing a path to a service account key JSON file
const serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
initializeApp({
  credential: cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

@example

```
// Providing a service account object inline
initializeApp({
  credential: cert({
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    clientEmail: "foo@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----<KEY>-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

@returns
A credential authenticated via the provided service account that can be used to initialize an app.

---

Comment: You explain it better than the docs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So after some time I figured out that the service account file must be within the functions folder. Then make the path relative or in my example: ./test-eed0a-firebase-adminsdk-c4tmt-5d905a082b.json. This should work.